# How can I add a folder with Business Objects RESTful Web Services SDK?

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am using version 4.2 of the BO RESTful SDK, upgrading an application from the 3.X Java SDK.  In the application, there is a requirement for creating a new folder in the BO environment. In the old Java SDK, this was achievable like this:

```
IFolder favoritesFolder = infoStore.getMyFavoritesFolder();    
IInfoObject newFolder = favoritesFolder.add(CeKind.FOLDER);
```

In the documentation for the RESTful SDK, I can't seem to find a parallel for creating a new folder like this. Is it possible to create a folder programatically in the new SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder management via the BIP RESTful Web Service is available from BI 4.2 SP3 onwards.

As the [manual](http://help.sap.com/bobip#section7) states (paragraph 6.12.2, *Creating a Folder*):

> Make a request to the `v1/folders/folder` URL to create a folder in
>   the BI platform.
>
> - Use the `GET` method to retrieve an XML template for the request body.
> - Use the `POST` method to create a folder in the BI platform.

Comment: It appears I don't have SP3 and as such this wasn't in the documentation I had.  Thanks.